# SEU - Is there a way to automate changing of these SEU defaults?

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, pdm

I need to often switch IBM i machines and need to set-it up for my use and this SEU change is one of them.
Is there any system command or API or SQL service that can be used to automate this process?

[image: SEU(F13)]

Can we identify what PF/table is updated using EDTOPTS??

[image: DSPF: QPDA/QDSUDSPF RCDFMT: EDTOPTS]

Here are the call stack entries.
[image]

Comment: You realize that the last OS version that SEU supported fully was v6.1 we are fully 5 major releases from that point. You might as well be using notepad.

Comment: I totally understand this @jmarkmurphy, In fact I encourage the use of RDi and Code for i, but reality is most shops prefer green-screen from the renaissance and some apps are best tested there and these SEU settings come handy for tweaking of sources.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to change the defaults any other way. The defaults are not held in a PF/table. (I don't know where they **are** held, but I do know it's not anything we can access.)

Comment: Oh alright. I thought if there's CHGPDMDFT for PDM, there might be something for SEU as well that I couldn't find on internet. Thanks for your reply Barbara.